# Is there a way to prevent CALayer shadows from overlapping adjacent layers?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a collection of `CALayers`. Each layer is a sublayer of the same parent `CALayer`, and each has a shadow applied to it. The layers are positioned dynamically, and there are many of them, so I can't predict how they'll be arranged ahead of time.

If the layers are adjacent to each other (close enough that they are almost touching) the shadow of one of the `CALayers` is rendered on top of the other `CALayer`. That's probably the desired effect in most cases, but I want my layers to exist in the same z-plane. (An example of this is the way **CSS3** shadows are applied to block elements in web design.)

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

(I had this idea: Adding a 'shadow' sublayer to each `CALayer` with my own shadow image, and setting the z-position to a lower value. But doesn't the layer-tree make this impossible? Z-positions in one layer's coordinate system are independent from z-positions in another layer's coordinate system, right?)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If all of the shadowed layers have the same shadow settings, put them into a container layer and set the shadow on the container layer.  Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CALayer *containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
    containerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    containerLayer.shadowRadius = 10;
    containerLayer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:containerLayer];

    CAShapeLayer *layer1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    layer1.position = CGPointMake(130, 130);
    layer1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:layer1.bounds].CGPath;
    layer1.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [containerLayer addSublayer:layer1];

    CAShapeLayer *layer2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    layer2.position = CGPointMake(170, 200);
    layer2.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:layer2.bounds].CGPath;
    layer2.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    [containerLayer addSublayer:layer2];
}
```

Output:

[image: overlapping circles with unified shadow]

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is so obvious in hindsight. The idea did occur to me, but I figured it would have applied a shadow to the shape of the container layer (whatever that is, haha).