# Prevent UICollectionViewCell drop shadow from casting onto other cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, calayer

I'm hoping someone might have a clever solution to this problem, because at the moment, I'm stumped. I have a collectionView whose cell's all cast fairly large drop shadows onto the area behind them. The problem is that since they are so close together, each cell is also casting a shadow onto the immediately preceding cell. All of these cells have the same zIndex in their layoutAttributes, but Apple seems to be placing the cells with the higher indexPath values at a higher zIndex. Is there a good way to prevent these cells from casting their shadows onto the other cells?

The cells are setting their shadow via:

```
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 54
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 12)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your latest attempt? And what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Set the shadow properties of the collection view's layer, instead of setting them on each cell. Make sure the collection view has no `backgroundView` and that its `backgroundColor` is nil. Also make sure some ancestor view of the collection view does have a background color or some other fill.

Result:

[image]

Source code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var cellIdentifier: String { return "cell" }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4)

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = nil
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        collectionView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        collectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        collectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        self.view = view
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let layer = cell.contentView.layer
        layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure, but that adds a single shadow to the collectionView's layer.  I still want to have multiple shadows that trace the shape of each cell.  And I still want the shadows to follow each cell as they get scrolled from right to left.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484208/77567) for example.

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. It added a shadow to the rect that defines the collectionViews area. The example you linked doesn't wrap two views in a parent view; it wraps two *layers* in a parent layer.

Comment: Does your collection view have an opaque background? What if you set the background color to clear or nil?

Comment: Each view draws itself on screen using a layer, and every parent/child relationship in the view tree is represented directly in the layer tree. I have added a working example of this technique to my answer.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Works perfectly in my case. I never would have thought of that, thanks!

Comment: This also works in UITableView cells, in iOS 14, remember to set the cell's `backgroundConfiguration` property to `.clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wasn't able to find a good way to prevent these shadows from casting onto the surrounding cells, but I think I found a working solution. I am going to add decoration views that layout directly underneath the cells, and then add the shadows to those views. It's a bit of a hack, but it should produce the effect I'm going for.